# Ionic Build Error in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am creating a mobile application in Ionic Framework.Now am trying to take the APK file.But it shows error.The error is as follows 
1)/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
2)Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I am new in Ionic Framework,Anyone please help me

Comment: did you try ``ionic serve``

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Roll back to build-tools 23. Worked for me.